# Load Cell Bridge Resistances are ok but I cannot get reading from load cell

Tags: sensor, load-cell, bridge

I have planar beam load cells that are not functioning. I bought a digitizer which was giving me a reading error which alerted me to an issue. So I unplug the cells from the summation box and I am checking with a multimeter. I checked the bridge voltages and they are all the same which is good. I am puzzled by the mV/V value. I put 5V on the excitation leads with a PSU and I got a reading 1.2V on the signal leads.

Why would the bridge resistance be OK but the mV/V fail? Are these load cells dead? What would be a final test? I tried pressing on the load cell while powered and the Multimeter just gives me a constant value.

Any ideas?

**some details on the load cells**

- Rated Output (RO) mV/V 1 ± 10% 0.9 ± 0.1%
- Calibration in mV/V/Ω % n.a. ± 0.05
- Zero balance %*RO ± 5
- Excitation voltage V 5...15
- Input resistance (RLC) Ω 1,180 ± 50
- Output resistance (Rout) Ω 1,000 ± 10
- Insulation resistance (100 V DC) MΩ ≥ 5,000
- Safe load limit (Elim) %*Emax 300
- Ultimate load %*Emax 400
- Safe side load %*Emax 200

*** UPDATE ***

I have four of these [Load cells](https://www.flintec.com/media/datasheets/pb-datasheet-en.pdf) which go to a [junction box](https://www.flintec.com/electronics/load-cell-junction-boxes/kp-kpk). I take readings through the [digitizer](https://www.flintec.com/electronics/digitising-units/em100). The setup used to be functional so I know at one time everything worked. For some reason after some time idle, I cannot take readings. The load cells where never dropped or anything so I am a bit surprised I cannot get a reading off of any of them. I am not sure how they could spontaneously die completely. The idle time was on the order of months say 5 months of non use.

One caveat to all this is that I used these load cells in a moist environment. 95% humidity. I know moisture is not your friend, but these things have this black tar looking stuff, I think they called it potting, on it.  Could this be a failure mode and could it derp four load cells?

[image: Rough Wiring Diagram]

Comment: You really need to show your circuit arrangement. Some of the simple flat load cells can be set up as 1/2 or 1/4 of a full bridge. Are you sure you know the correct arrangement of the output wires? Also the rated mV/V is full scale so you need to apply the full rated load to the specific load point (with other ends fixed) to see the rated output.  At a lower applied force (mass) you will get a fraction of the rated mV/V. (A link to the parts you are using would help too.)

Comment: @Nedd I updated the question with more details including links. This setup worked a few months ago so it is a head scratcher as to what happened. The digitizer appears to work as I can communicate with it but the readings always fail. So I want to see if the load cells need to be replaced.

Comment: If you apply 5V from +Excitation to -Excitation then measure from either Signal output back to -Excitation you should get 2.5V, then measuring between the +/- Signal outputs should give you a reading very close to 0V. To see the full mV/V reading (+Signal to -Signal) you would need a 4 or 5 digit multi-meter with at least 1mV resolution, (and the rated load applied to that load cell). When testing a single load cell the other load cells should not be connected. If the system has been in an environment with possible infestation check for chewed wires though all system wiring.